# How to skip startup jobs for fstab? No timeout CENTOS7

Tags: disk-encryption, systemd, fstab, centos-7

I was working on CentOS7 by encrypting one of my drives which worked perfectly manually.

However, after making a mistake in the `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab` for mounting automatically it will get stuck looping indefinitely at

> ```
> [***]A start job is running for dev-mapper-crypto.device
> ```

Any ideas on how to bypass this?

I tried running in runlevel 1 but it will try to mount it.

Comment: I did some digging and I used emergency mode (Thanks to gawity) and mounting on rw my root partition with mount / -o remount,rw which I found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383595/repairing-fstab-read-only#383842

Answer (score 3):

Boot with the `emergency` option (or `-b` for short) – this *will* skip almost everything. In case this leaves the root file system read-only, you can run `mount -o remount,rw /` once in the shell.

Or, boot with the `systemd.debug-shell` option – this will give you a shell on tty9 even while the system is booting. Then you can `systemctl list-jobs` and `systemctl cancel`.

Or, boot with the `systemd.mask=mnt-whatever.mount` – this will force systemd to ignore just that specific unit file. (Every fstab mount corresponds to a `.mount` unit, where `/` replaced is with `-`. For example, `/mnt/my-data` is `mnt-my\x2ddata.mount`.)

---

(Side note: systemd has no runlevels; the boot option for single-user mode is just that, `single`.)

Comment: OMG you are a life saver! I used the emergency option and it worked! Now I will just remove the /etc/fstab entries. thanks!

Comment: Ugh now I cant edit the fstab :S

Comment: Try `mount -o remount,rw /` or boot with `emergency rw` instead of the usual `ro`.

Comment: I used mount / -o remount,rw and fixed it thanks again :)